# Migrating a website from one stack to another reports different data on the new analytics

Tags: google-analytics, migration

- My site domain is example.com
- There are 2 different stacks behind it (stack A which is the old stack and stack B which is the one we are migrating to). Both stacks have Google Analytics set up.
- Some routes has been migrated to stack B (e.g. example.com/route1, example.com/route2, etc.). Other routes are still on stack A.
- For some reason, when migrating like that, the number of daily average users on the migrated routes is going down. We are trying to figure out why.

Is there any chance 2 Google Analytics setups messed up the data?

Comment: GA is passive. It only measures what it sees.

Comment: There are some setting in GA such as filters that could be messing up the data.   Your new stack could be missing the GA tag on some pages.   Other than those possible issues, it sounds like your new stack may be getting less traffic.